# How to change branch and pull from another branch?

Tags: git, github

I'm kind of new to Git and I don't feel safe running commands.
I'm working on Branch A and I made a lot of changes. I need to work on another branch (Branch B) that doesn't have the files of Branch A.
I'm not ready to make a merge of the branches.

Is it the right way if I `commit` and `push` to Branch A then `fetch --all` and `checkout` to Branch B. Then I `pull` from Branch B do the required work with the files of Branch B and `commit` and `push` in Branch B to later return to Branch A and `pull` the pushed files I made before?

I read about `stash` but I'm not sure if in this case it would be useful.

Comment: I recommend *avoiding* `git stash`. If your Git is at least version 2.15, use `git worktree` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of a matter of opinion, but I don't like stashing if I don't have to; if I'm in the middle of unfinished work on Branch A and I'm told to work on Branch B, I do an add-and-commit with a `wip` commit message (to indicate that this is "work in progress"), and then `git fetch; git switch branchB`.

No need to say `fetch --all`. No need to push Branch A (and it's probably a bad idea to do so, since it isn't baked yet). No need to pull because the `fetch` updated everything.

But if you *already had* a local Branch B, then after you switch to Branch B you might need to say `git merge` to update the local branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the work done on branch A and switch to branch B, then later return to your unfinished work on branch A you could:

1. `git stash push` (save your uncommited work to stash);
2. `git checkout B` (switch branch to B);
3. `git pull` (integrate the latest remote state into B);
4. do some work;
5. `git add <pathspec> && git commit` (commit your work on Branch B);

When you are ready to continue on branch A you would do:

6. `git checkout A`(switch branch to A);
7. `git stash pop` (apply the state previously saved to stash).

Comment: This is isn't wrong, but note that I disagree on all counts. This is why I said in my answer it's a matter of opinion! I am opposed to the use of `stash` and to the use of `pull`. So you see, OP, you thought you were asking a simple question but you've accidentally fallen into a religious war! :)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why are you opposed to the use of `stash`?

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov: I can't speak for matt but `git stash` is a horribly complicated command, that in "make new" mode, makes either two or three commits, one of which is technically a merge commit, and none of which are on any branch. Later, you must use `git stash` in apply mode (with any of three verbs) to make use of one, two, or all three commits. The most commonly used verb, `pop`, then *loses* all the commits so that if you've misused the verb or its options you must go *find* the commits (which is potentially very difficult) and/or you may have wrecked some in-progress work.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you use any other non-stash command *on* the two-or-three commits, those commands will treat the technically-a-merge-commit *as* a merge commit, even though it's not the normal result of a normal merge process. So this will often produce nonsense. Because `refs/stash` refers to the topmost stash's merge commit, it's very easy to run `git show stash` instead of `git stash show`: users become confused. They then use `git stash` with a wrong verb or flags or at the wrong time and make a mess and lose the saved stash and become frustrated. It's a bad scene.